how do I make x have a value
<html>
<input `type="text"` `id="insert1"`><br>
<input `type="button"` `value="sdsssssdsdsd"`>
<p `id="demo"`></p>
<p `id="craz"`></p>

<script>
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
x = document.getElementById("insert1").value;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits.includes(x);
document.getElementById("craz").innerHTML = x

</script>

</html>

I want x to have a value so that fruits.includes(x) is going to result to be true. But whenever I input a value, it doesn't change. I've tried making it into a function but the script just breaks completely. What do I do?your text

Start with removing the backticks ``` from element attributes

Why is this tagged with java?

"But whenever I input a value, it doesn't change": you need an event handler. Put your fruits finding code in a function, and then call addEventListener("input", yourFunction) on the input element.
